# Nested ng-Repeat not working angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code is like this

```
<table ng-app='myApp'>
    <thead>

    </thead>
    <tbody ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <tr ng-repeat="prdElement in palletElement">
            <td>{{prdElement.name}}</td>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in prdElement.data">

                <td>
                    {{data.itemId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.shipmentId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.itemCode}}
                <td>
                    {{data.description}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    {{data.handlingUnit}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.weight}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.class}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.lenght}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    {{data.width}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.height}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.flag}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="prdElement.quantity" placeholder="Code" required />
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="newPalletItem(palletElement,$event)">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>


(function () {
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

        var counter = 0;

        $scope.palletElement =
        [{
            name: 'Pallet 1',
            Data:[{
            name:'item 1' ,
            itemId: '284307',
            shipmentId: 'eb44f690-c97a-40e3-be2a-0449559e171a',
            itemCode: '',
            description: 'Bicycle parts - frame',
            quantity: '31',
            handlingUnit: 'CTN',
            weight: '613.04',
            class:'',
            lenght: '102',
            width: '42',
            height: '61',
            flag:'P'
        }, {
            name: 'item 2',
            itemId: '284308',
            shipmentId: 'eb44f690-c97a-40e3-be2a-0449559e171a',
            itemCode: '',
            description: 'Bicycle parts - fork',
            quantity: '22',
            handlingUnit: 'CTN',
            weight: '242.99',
            class: '',
            lenght: '75',
            width: '34',
            height: '18',
            flag: 'P'
        }]
        }]

    }
    });
}());
```

All looks okay to me, but not working, can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9k7f7cu/1/)**

Comment: If i am not wrong, you are doing a `<tr>` inside a `<tr>` . You might have misplaced the tags

Comment: Also, `{{data.itemCode}}` has no ending `</td>` tag.

Comment: @LearningNeverStops Okay. Any guess on why its not working?

Comment: @Athul How about fixed those syntax errors in your fiddle first?

Comment: @isim Done. Still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` from `tbody` and add it on `table`

Change `prdElement.data` To `prdElement.Data` and Try

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k2zwuqqt/)

Comment: The `ng-controller` can remain in the `tbody`. OP just needs to fix up the javascript syntax error. Also, those [nested `<tr>` elements are malformed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr).

Comment: My own experience with attempting to nest `<tr>` tags with nested repeaters resulted in the repeater just kind of giving up. No console errors, just the repeater refusing to work. I'm assuming angular has some kind of syntax checking or some such in repeaters, not sure. The solution was to use nested `<ul>` tags, which is valid and totally fine to do and the repeater doesn't have a problem with those.